`npm publish --provenance` failed with `TLOG_CREATE_ENTRY_ERROR` "error creating tlog entry - (502) Bad Gateway"
When running npm publish --provenance in GitHub Actions, this error appeared today:
https://github.com/prisma/prisma/actions/runs/9466219272/job/26077403391#step:5:472
npm notice Tarball Details
npm notice name: @prisma/debug
npm notice version: 5.16.0-dev.27
npm notice filename: prisma-debug-5.16.0-dev.27.tgz
npm notice package size: 8.9 kB
npm notice unpacked size: 25.2 kB
npm notice shasum: f634f71080e8e70460ed1d9337b78f6b26b0eee9
npm notice integrity: sha512-/E4ogIwD0Etdw[...]k12RvhsdJRhKw==
npm notice total files: 7
npm notice
npm notice Publishing to https://registry.npmjs.org/ with tag dev and public access
npm error code TLOG_CREATE_ENTRY_ERROR
npm error error creating tlog entry - (502) Bad Gateway

I think the TLOG_CREATE_ENTRY_ERROR error comes from https://github.com/sigstore/sigstore-js which is used by npm CLI.
https://status.npmjs.org does not mention any incident.
I found this status page: https://status.sigstore.dev/ which has no recent incident.
Did anyone else got this error?

This is now an incident https://status.npmjs.org/incidents/2v41lbhcj771
"The issue has been identified and a fix is being implemented."

This issue was identified by the npm team and is now resolved.
More info at https://status.npmjs.org/incidents/2v41lbhcj771
